# Import String date from CSV to mytable

Tags: mysql

I have a date in a csv file which is in the string format

The format is like this

Sat Jun 13 2015 06:56:56 GMT+0200 (CEST)

Is it possible to load the same format in mysql table.

I wanted the above string date in the same format in timestamp format int he table. Is it possible?

Could anybody guide me ?

Thanks

Comment: You can use [`STR_TO_DATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) in your `INSERT` statement.

Comment: I used str_to_date , but my question, is it possible to get the exact format as in the csv file with GMT+0200 (CEST). Could you tell me how to pass the value to STR_TO_DATE with GMT+0200 (CEST)?